# Why does one of my Material UI autocomplete elements have a blue background for the options, but the other doesn't? (includes code sandbox)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-hook-form, yup

FINAL EDIT: I ended up finding a fix and I updated my sandbox with it!

EDIT: I have determined that it is due to this line in the autocomplete...

```
isOptionEqualToValue={(option, value) => option.id === value.id}
```

However, if I try to change it to this...

```
isOptionEqualToValue={(option, value) => option.label === value.label}
```

I get the following error in the console...

> useAutocomplete.js:219 MUI: The value provided to Autocomplete is
> invalid. None of the options match with `"Lisinopril"`. You can use
> the `isOptionEqualToValue` prop to customize the equality test.

---

I have created the following form using Material UI and React Hook Form...

https://codesandbox.io/s/inputquestion-jyq5b?file=/src/App.js

I am very stumped on why the two autocomplete elements are styled differently with a light blue background for the options/the options' hovers, but the other one isn't.

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide!

Comment: Both look same in your shared [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/inputquestion-jyq5b?file=/src/App.js). In your case, one of the autocomplete's light background could be due to `browser is auto filling` the input and showing a `light blue` background for that autocomplete.

Answer (score 1):

Probably because the one with the `disabledPortal` prop is rendered inside the container (Box) with the applied style. The other one has the default `disablePortal` value set to false so it is rendered using react portal thus outside the Box. Try setting this prop the same and see if they are the same.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I tried adding disablePortal to the medication form element, but it did not change the color of the option background. Is that what you meant for me to try?